# Is there a jQuery plugin for doing in-page paged searches?

Tags: jquery, plugins, jquery-animate, pagedlist

I have a simple search box, whose results I want to appear in a div within a page. Usually there should be no more than 3 results, but bizarrely, for some rare cases, there may 100+ !
I wondered if anyone had/knew of a paged results plugin for jQuery. I've tried rolling my own, but having issues with (a) queuing the animations when I replace the default text with the results (b) and paging between results using links within the replaced result listing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the [Pagination](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/pagination) plugin.

- [Documentation](https://github.com/gbirke/jquery_pagination#readme)
- [Demo](http://d-scribe.de/webtools/jquery-pagination/demo/demo_options.htm)